# file i/o in c++

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream, ifstream

all i want to do is print the contents of readme.txt 20 times.. please help.

```
int main()
{
        ifstream myfile;
        string line;
        int i;
        myfile.open ("readme.txt");

        if (myfile.is_open()){
                while (i<20){
                        i++;
                        if(!myfile.eof()){
                                cout << "asdasd" << "\t";
                                myfile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
                        }
                        getline (myfile,line);
                        cout << line << endl;
                }
                cout << endl;
                myfile.close();
        }
        else cout << "Unable to open file";
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: and what's the problem ?

Comment: its doesnt seem to work... all i get is the file printed once and then the string "asdasd" printed 10 times (as the getline also increments i) and the file is 10 lines long....

Comment: Have you stepped through your code line by line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the jobs man :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
 std::ifstream myfile;
 std::string content;
 std::string line;
 myfile.open ("Readme.txt");

 if (myfile.is_open()){

  if(!myfile.eof())
  {
   getline (myfile,line);      
   content.append(line);
  }

  while (!myfile.eof()){
   getline (myfile,line);   
   content.append("\n");
   content.append(line);
  }

  myfile.close();

  for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
   std::cout << content << std::endl;
 }
 else std::cout << "Unable to open file";
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a simple solution. For high performance with very big files, consider using a stringstream instead.

Answer (score 1):

there are several problems with your code.  first i isn't initialized. Second reading the contents of the file should be done once before the loop not after, you should print the contents of the file where asdasd is printed to see the contents of the file printed as many times as the loop runs.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this (pseudocode):

```
if(file is open)
{
   for(int i = 0; i<20; ++i)
   {
     while(getline(file, line))
     {
       print line
     }
     seek to 0
   }
   close file
}
```

***Edit:*** In fact your real problem is the uninitialized variable `i`. The deeper reason was that you used `while` where `for` was more appropriate

Comment: Unless they've edited the question the getline is inside the loop.

Comment: @Moo @Kiril @Dev @Ash OK OK I get it, relax :)

Comment: @Ash, Question, at time of writing, is unedited.  But still, doesn't matter, there's plenty else wrong with this code sample :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you are printing `asdasd` if you are NOT at the end of the file.

Comment: Even so, cout << line has got anything to do with the if

Comment: @Ash, no and that's not the issue.  He's outputting and rewinding to the beginning of the file each line, from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
int i;
```

and this `i` is not initialized.

Comment: So, what's the problem at all ?

Comment: By default the c++ compiler initializes integers to 0 for no value if given.

Comment: I think this is compiler-specific and the standard doesn't say anything about that. Don't think anyone can rely on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!myfile.eof())
```

You might want to lose the `!`. You are rewinding to the beginning of the file on each loop.

(Kiril also has a point here...)

Comment: i did that unintentionally... removed it... still the prob persists.. :P

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("readme.txt");
    std::vector<char> filebuffer;

    ifs.seekg (0, std::ios::end);
    size_t size = static_cast<size_t>(ifs.tellg());
    ifs.seekg (0, std::ios::beg);

    filebuffer.resize(size);
    ifs.read(&filebuffer[0], size);

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        std::copy(filebuffer.begin(), filebuffer.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fix your problem but your structure is pretty bad. Use a while when you don't know how many times you want to loop, otherwise use a for loop. Something like below should be ok

```
int main()
{
    ifstream myfile;
    string content;
    string line;
    myfile.open ("readme.txt");
    while(!myfile.eof()){
            getline (myfile,line);
            content += line;
    }
    myfile.close();

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
            cout << content << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will add the last line twice. (Making `line` as tightly scoped as possible - as is usually recommended - would at least change this to an empty line appended.)

Comment: i just wrote the code from memory... thats why so many mistakes.. anyways thank u for ur answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you wanna do that but this code works:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    std::fstream myfile;
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {    
        myfile.open("main.cpp",std::fstream::in);
        if (myfile)
        {
           cout << myfile.rdbuf() << endl;
           cout << "FINISH" << endl;
        }
        else
           cout << "Error" << endl;
        myfile.close();
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

If the file is not changing during the iteration, this is even better

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>

 using std::cout;
 using std::endl;

 int main(int argc,char* argv[])
 { 
    std::fstream myfile;
    myfile.open("main.cpp",std::fstream::in);
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {    
        if (myfile)
        {
            cout << myfile.rdbuf() << endl;
            cout << "FINISH" << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << "Error" << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You should hit the editor button to reformat that code as code -- looks pretty funny like this.